# pgadmin4 stuck in indefinet loading screen -- Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am running postgresql in Docker Container. I was connected to it using Pgadmin4 and it was all good until past hour or so and suddenly stopped working. its stuck in loading screen and its not working. I tried to uninstall postgres, pgadmin but nothing really worked.

I used the below commands

```
sudo apt autoremove pgadmin4
```

I have postgis installed if that helps

[Indefinite loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntlqg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a work around and thought it would be helpful to anyone who has similar issues.

`Ubuntu 18.04`

1. `sudo apt remove pgadmin4`
2. `sudo rm -rf /home/${USER}/.config/pgadmin`
3. `sudo apt install pgadmin4`

Hopefully that should work if anyone has a better answer please advice.